# Artifical Neural Netword Normalization

Tags: php, neural-network

I am a new comer to ANN and i was hoping someone would help me understand the concept of normalization with an example as the following. preferable in php, just a small clear example will do.

Lets say >>

```
    Rooms               Area              Type 
     1                   350               Apartment
     1                   800               Apartment
     3                   300               Apartment
     8                   1500              House
     7                   900               house
     1                   800               flat
```

how can i normalize this data? most of the books that read regrading ANN states that the out put has to come as 0 or 1, where do this values come from?

I want the system to be able to tell the difference between a flat, house and apartments.
please give me an example in Php code.
thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: With this little data you can normalize what you want, your neural net is never going to work it out. :-) Normalisation is not that hard: v' = (v - mean) / std dev. You can install this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php to make computing the std dev slightly easier... but it is so simple that you don't really need it.

Comment: I just gave you a simple example i could have populated more then 10,000. i am just trying to give you an example here there could be plenty of flats with different measurement styles or different room numbers. that is why i need to do this using ANN.

Comment: Well, give it a try, make something in PHP. If you run into specific problems you can always ask questions here.

Comment: My question is how does normalization works in this case? i have never done this before but i am sure that it ANN case.

Comment: I'm sorry but an explanation of normalization in the context of ANN can be found, if you look for it. SO is here to help you with coding problems, not to explain basic concepts and then write the PHP code for you. So, be on topic: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and show what you have tried so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I do realize you're new to SO, but please read these explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a classification problem (as it seems from the data), you don't need to normalize the output. So, you need to normalize the input value only. If you are using numpy in Python, you can normalize it in the following two ways:

1. Gaussian Normalization (0 mean and 1 std): This normalizes the data to have zero mean and st deviation equal to 1.

   xNor = (x-x.mean())/x.std()
2. (0, 1) Range Normalization: This normalizes the data to the range (0, 1).

   xNor = (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())

To vectorize the output, you can use one-vs-all classification or binary-encoding classification. I would personally recommend one-vs-all classification. You can refer to this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification